# Firefox 57+ loading of unsigned webextensions

Tags: firefox, code-signing, firefox-addon-webextensions

**My understanding is that Mozilla:**

- **will not** allow installation of unsigned webextensions into the regular version of Firefox 57+.
- **will** allow installation of unsigned webextensions into the Developer channel of Firefox 57+.
- **will** allow installation of unsigned webextensions into the Nightly channel of Firefox 57+ **for now**.

**Is that correct?**

Comment: Are you specifically asking about *installing* an add-on through the normal add-on installation process, or are you including loading an add-on temporarily? Hint: Nothing's changed in this regard with Firefox 57+. The thing that has changed is that installing non-WebExtension based extensions, and complete themes, is disabled on the release and beta versions of Firefox 57+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... Nightly, Developer and Unbranded editions can load unsigned add-ons (otherwise it will not be possible to develop and test add-ons before distribution).